# Is it possible to use both hyperxmp and xmpincl in LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, metadata, xmp

I am trying to add other xmp metadata to a pdf file which is not covered by hyperxmp. I tried to use both hyperxmp and xmpincl. Building the project in TeXnicCenter produces no errors, so I am thinking including and using both packages is okay. But when I extract the xmp file through a java code, the only xmp metadata stored in the xmp file is those created with hyperxmp. Am I doing something wrong, or it is really not possible to use both packages?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly use the packages [`hyperxmp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) and [`xmpincl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xmpincl) together in one document, as you'll end up with a PDF file including two incompatible XMP metadata entries. However, you can reuse the XMP code produced by `hyperxmp` as suggested in [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperxmp/hyperxmp.pdf):

> `hyperxmp` and `xmpincl` can complement each other. An author may want to use `hyperxmp` to produce a basic set of XMP code, then extract the XMP code from the PDF file with a text editor, augment the XMP code with any metadata not supported by `hyperxmp`, and use `xmpincl` to include the modied XMP code in the PDF file.

To facilitate this process a bit, you can create a document `metadata.tex` where you set all the metadata using `hyperxmp` and write the resulting XMP code to a file `metadata.xmp`:

#### `metadata.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\newwrite\xmpmetadata
\makeatletter
\hyxmp@at@end{%
  % Create XMP code and write it to macro \hyxmp@xml
  % (cf. hyperxmp.sty, \hyxmp@construct@packet (ll. 847-868))
  \gdef\hyxmp@xml{}%
  \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="3.1-702">^^J%
___<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns\hyxmp@hash">^^J%
  }%
  \hyxmp@pdf@schema
  \hyxmp@xmpRights@schema
  \hyxmp@dc@schema
  \hyxmp@photoshop@schema
  \hyxmp@photometa@schema
  \hyxmp@xmp@basic@schema
  \hyxmp@mm@schema
  \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
___</rdf:RDF>^^J%
</x:xmpmeta>^^J%
  }%
  % Write content of \hyxmp@xml to file metadata.xmp
  \immediate\openout\xmpmetadata=metadata.xmp%
  \immediate\write\xmpmetadata{\hyxmp@xml}%
  \immediate\closeout\xmpmetadata%
}
\makeatother

% Specify the XMP metadata here
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Author},
  pdftitle={Title},
  pdfcopyright={(c) 2013 by Author}
}

\begin{document}
The purpose of this document is to generate a file \texttt{metadata.xmp} containing XMP metadata.
\end{document}
```

This will produce a file `metadata.xmp`, which you can modify according to your needs and include it into your main document afterwards:

#### `document.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xmpincl}
\includexmp{metadata}

\begin{document}
This is the main document, using the XMP metadata found in \texttt{metadata.xml}.
\end{document}
```