# Validate pdf with and without pdfx

Tags: hyperref, pdf, pdfx, hyperxmp

The following document, which uses `hyperref`, illustrates two ways of embedding metadata into the output from pdflatex:

1. Using the `pdfx` package with option `a-2u` — this happens when the flag `validate` is set to `true`, as it is below.
2. Using instead the `hyperxmp` package with `\hyperrefset` including options `pdfapart=2, pdfaconformance=u` — this happens if the flag `validate` is set to 'false`.

Both methods seem to embed essentially the same metadata about title, author, etc., into the pdf.

The pdf output file passes PDF/A-2U validation (with the veraPDF app, e.g.) with method 1.
However, it *fails* validation with method 2. (See an extract from the veraPDF report, at the end.)

**Question:**  What can be done to allow validation to succeed with method 2?

**Source:**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname metadata.xmp}
\hyxmp@at@end{%
  % Create XMP code and write it to macro \hyxmp@xml
  % (cf. hyperxmp.sty, \hyxmp@construct@packet (ll. 847-868))
  \gdef\hyxmp@xml{}%
  \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="3.1-702">^^J%
___<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns\hyxmp@hash">^^J%
  }%
  \hyxmp@pdf@schema
  \hyxmp@xmpRights@schema
  \hyxmp@dc@schema
  \hyxmp@photoshop@schema
  \hyxmp@photometa@schema
  \hyxmp@xmp@basic@schema
  \hyxmp@mm@schema
  \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
___</rdf:RDF>^^J%
</x:xmpmeta>^^J%
  }%
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Title{A Book}
\Author{Anonymous}
\Language{en-US}
\Keywords{things\sep stuff}
\Subject{matters}
\Publisher{Anonymous}
\Copyright{\copyright 2020 The Company CC-BY-NC-ND}
\CopyrightURL{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/}
\PublicationType{book}
\Lastpage{3}
\Date{2020-06-26}
\CoverDisplayDate{June\ 26,\ 2020}
\CoverDate{2020-06-26}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{validate}
\setboolean{validate}{true}  

\ifthenelse{\boolean{validate}}%
  {\RequirePackage[a-2u]{pdfx}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{EM}{0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{NUL}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
    \RequirePackage[type={CC},modifier={by-nc-nd},version={4.0},lang={english}]{doclicense}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
       pdfa,
       bookmarksnumbered,
       pdftitle={A Book}, pdfauthor={Anonymous}, pdfcreator={somebody},
       pdfsubject={A general introducton to things}, pdfkeywords={things, stuff},
   }  %  
}%
  {\RequirePackage{hyperxmp} % to add CC info into pdf
   \RequirePackage[type={CC},modifier={by-nc-nd},version={4.0},lang={english}]{doclicense}
   \usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
      pdfapart=2, pdfaconformance=u,
      bookmarksnumbered,
      pdftitle={A Book}, pdfauthor={Anonymous}, pdfcreator={somebody},
      pdfsubject={A general introducton to things}, pdfkeywords={things, stuff},
      pdflicenseurl={http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/}
    }%
    \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3} file{sRGB.icc}
    \pdfcatalog{%
        /OutputIntents [
           <<
             /Type /OutputIntent
             /S /GTS_PDFA2
             /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
             /OutputConditionIdentifier (sRGB)
             /Info (sRGB)
          >>
      ]
    }
}

\newcommand\mytitle{A Book}
\newcommand\myauthor{Anonymous}
\newcommand\myabstract{An introduction to things in general.}
\newcommand\mydate{\today}
\title{\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor}
\date{\mydate}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[french,ngerman,russian,main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

**Validation failure report for method 2:**

```
<rule specification="ISO 19005-2:2011" clause="6.2.4.3" testNumber="4" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="230">
   <description>DeviceGray shall only be used if a device independent DefaultGray colour space has been set when the DeviceGray colour space is used,
    or if a PDF/A OutputIntent is present.</description>
   <object>PDDeviceGray</object>
   <test>gOutputCS != null</test>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[2](23 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](24 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[170]/fillCS[0]</context>
   </check>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[2](23 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](24 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[168]/fillCS[0]</context>
   </check>
   .... [many more similar failures] 
</rule>
<rule specification="ISO 19005-2:2011" clause="6.2.11.7" testNumber="1" status="failed" passedChecks="0" failedChecks="27">
   <description>The Font dictionary of all fonts shall define the map of all used character codes to Unicode values, either via a ToUnicode entry,
    or other mechanisms as defined in ISO 19005-2, 6.2.11.7.2.</description>
   <object>Glyph</object>
   <test>toUnicode != null</test>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[2](23 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](24 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[150]/usedGlyphs[1](YKMMCJ+NewTXMI 67 0  0)</context>
   </check>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[2](23 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](24 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[150]/usedGlyphs[0](YKMMCJ+NewTXMI 109 0  0)</context>
   </check>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[2](23 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](24 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[135]/usedGlyphs[0](PGXZDZ+txmiaX 8 0  0)</context>
   </check>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[2](23 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](24 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[123]/usedGlyphs[0](YKMMCJ+NewTXMI 50 0  0)</context>
   </check>
   .... [more like the above] 
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[1](12 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](13 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[601]/usedGlyphs[0](GEXQPI+txsys 0 0  0)</context>
   </check>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[1](12 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](13 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[595]/usedGlyphs[0](YKMMCJ+NewTXMI 63 0  0)</context>
   </check>
   <check status="failed">
     <context>root/document[0]/pages[1](12 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](13 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[580]/usedGlyphs[0](UOCZFW+txexs 112 0  0)</context>
   </check>
   .... [more like the above]
</rule>
```

**Related:**

[pdfx + hyperref prevents setting PDF metadata [incompatible packages]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510436/pdfx-hyperref-prevents-setting-pdf-metadata-incompatible-packages/510656#510656)

[Is it possible to use both hyperxmp and xmpincl in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139716/is-it-possible-to-use-both-hyperxmp-and-xmpincl-in-latex/141000#141000)

**Added 2020-06-29:**

I've continued in [How to find glyphs in pdf requiring \pdfglyphtounicode to allow validation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551625/how-to-find-glyphs-in-pdf-requiring-pdfglyphtounicode-to-allow-validation) the discussion begun in the comments to the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551291/13492.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following validates. The main error was that the subtype of the outputintent should be `/GTS_PDFA1`, `/GTS_PDFA2` doesn't exist according the pdf reference.

Beside this some glyph of your fonts hadn't and unicode representation, I added dummy meanings. I didn't try to include the additional xmp data.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\RequirePackage[type={CC},modifier={by-nc-nd},version={4.0},lang={english}]{doclicense}
 \usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
      pdfapart=2, pdfaconformance=u,
      bookmarksnumbered,
      pdftitle={A Book}, pdfauthor={Anonymous}, pdfcreator={somebody},
      pdfsubject={A general introducton to things}, pdfkeywords={things, stuff},
      pdflicenseurl={http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/}
    }%
    \input{glyphtounicode}
    \pdfgentounicode=1
    \pdfglyphtounicode{EM}{0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058 0058}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{NUL}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{uni222B.dsp}{222B}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{summationdisplay.1}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{summationdisplay}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%    
    \pdfglyphtounicode{radicalBigg}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{radicalbig}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
    \pdfglyphtounicode{radicalbigg}{0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060 0060}%
    \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3} file{sRGB.icc}
    \pdfcatalog{%
        /OutputIntents [
         <<
             /Type /OutputIntent
             /S /GTS_PDFA1
             /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
             /OutputConditionIdentifier (sRGB)
             /Info (sRGB)
          >>
      ]
    }

\newcommand\mytitle{A Book}
\newcommand\myauthor{Anonymous}
\newcommand\myabstract{An introduction to things in general.}
\newcommand\mydate{\today}
\title{\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor}
\date{\mydate}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[french,ngerman,russian,main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
abc abc
\maketitle
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the "pdf reference" to which you refer?

Comment: https://www.iso.org/standard/63534.html

Comment: ouch: the iso standards doc for PDF costs more than USD 200! How else might I determine which additional `\pdfglyphtounicode{...}{...}` commands I need to satisfy PDF validation. (In my real, book-length, document, I'm still getting many "The Font dictionary of all fonts shall define the map of all used character codes to Unicode values, either via a ToUnicode entry: rule failures referrring to glyphs in the MathTime Pro 2 fonts, e.g., in MT2MIT, MT2SYT, MT2SYS, MT2EXA, MTBMIT, MT2EXA, MT2SYF, MT2BYST fonts.

Comment: The glyphs are not in the reference.  Their names I found by looking into the uncompressed pdf.

Comment: What is meant by "the uncompressed pdf"? Is that the pdf that results from running pdflatex, or is it something else?

Comment: you can  set `\pdfcompresslevel=0` and `\pdfobjcompresslevel=0`. Then the pdf is ascii and you can open it in some editor and look at the content. (I normally use the expl3 variant `\RequirePackage{l3pdf}\ExplSyntaxOn\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff`  as it works with other engines too).

Comment: there is also an older version of the pdf reference around (for pdf until 1.7) which is free. Google for it (but be warned it has also around 1000 pages).

Comment: OK, now I can examine the uncompressed, ascii, pdf output. But what do I need to look for in order to determine what additional `\pdfglyphtounicode` commands I need for the file to pass pdf validation? (I need some hint in order to get started!)

Comment: well look at the example above and search e.g. for summationdisplay.1. Then you can try to guess how entries for other fonts look like.

Comment: I've continued this discussion at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551625/how-to-find-glyphs-in-pdf-requiring-pdfglyphtounicode-to-allow-validation